# Prometheus: Viewing __meta_* and __address__ labels

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

As [this](https://www.robustperception.io/life-of-a-label) blog post suggests, __meta_* labels are provided by service discovery mechanism in Prometheus and they are available for relabelling purposes. As the documentation suggests, such labels get removed later in the lifecycle and are not exposed in the web UI. 
Is there any way to view them prior to disposal for debugging purposes?

Comment: There are a fair amount of prometheus Q&As here and the software's core contributers are active here. I checked ServerFault and AskUbuntu and the number of questions about this topic are far less than the ones in stackoverflow. @jww

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find them on the service discovery status page, e.g. http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/service-discovery

Comment: Thanks Brian. You are always really helpful.